# how to use jquery in content script chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How to use Jquery in content.js.

Here is my code

**manifest.json**

```
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.12.2.min.js","background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.12.2.min.js","content.js"]
  }],
    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"

  ]
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.google.com/search?gws_rd=cr&as_qdr=all&q=" + encodeURIComponent(searchQ)}, function (tab){openSearchLink(tab)});
var createdTabId = 0;
function openSearchLink(tab){
    console.log("new tab "+tab.id);
    createdTabId = tab.id;

}
```

**content.js**

```
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    // If the received message has the expected format...
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        // Call the specified callback, passing
        // the web-page's DOM content as argument
        var resAry = {};
        console.log('dddd-'+$('#bname').val());
        resAry['bName'] = $('#bname').val().trim();
        sendResponse(resAry);
    }
});
```

resAry['bname'] is returning empty response. Where as, I am getting value when I use document.getElementById

Comment: first you can check your jQuery file is coming or not on the front end page ?? I check your Example It Shows Empty?

Comment: I don't have any front page/popup.html. I am trying to read dom content from the loaded tab

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Adding below line in popup.html did the trick

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the line?